# Is there a good tone generator web app for tuning arbitrary musical instruments?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a good web app for generating tones to help tune musical instruments?

Since some of the instruments I play are a little obscure (eg. a [guzheng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guzheng), which has 25 strings; a [charango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charango), for which it's common to change frequently between tunings) my fantasy feature wish list would be:

- Arbitrary pitches (eg. not limited to western scales)
- A way to step through a sequence of an arbitrary number of tones that that correspond to a particular tuning of a specific instrument
- Ability to save or link to such a sequence

Though I'd settle for a simple tone generator with a nice interface :)

Comment: I am a bit curious how you can be sure the computer will be playing the right tone?  Several years ago I had a computer generating a tone that was supposed to be 1000hz a frequency counter showed it was closer to 1050hz.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could find.  You can tweak the pitches by cents, play several preset series of pitches, and save your settings, but I don't think you can create your own series of pitches.

http://www.seventhstring.com/tuningfork/tuningfork.html

Comment: thanks, that sounds better that anything I've been able to find so far, but it's giving me a `403 Forbidden` error :(

Comment: @Ian Mackinnon: That's interesting, I just tried it again and it still works fine for me.  Can you access [this page](http://www.seventhstring.com/utilities/utilities.html)? It gives some troubleshooting suggestions.  Maybe try a different browser or computer and see if that makes a difference.